# usnig regular expressions, how any combination of certain characters can be eliminated from the beginning of a string

Tags: regex, plsql

In Oracle PL/SQL code, using regular expressions, how can I remove all occurrences of certain characters, in any combination, from the beginning of a string?

For example, consider the characters '+', '-', '=', and ' ' (space) at the beginning of the following input:

```
' ++ -+= =  - -=  +ABCD EFG + XYD'
```

then the output must be:

```
'ABCD EFG + XYD'
```

A solution I'm thinking of is like:

```
1) set the starting point of the search at the beginning of the input (using ^)
2) set the ending point of the search just before the first character which is not any of the 4 characters of interest.
3) replace all spaces with empty character : REGEXP_REPLACE(' +', '')
4) replace all + with empty character
5) replace all - with empty character 
6) replace all = with empty character
```

If this can be considered as a reasonable plan at all, I still don't know how item 2 above can be coded in regular expressions.

Thank you.

Comment: Why not use a simple LTRIM function?

Comment: I did not know that LTRIM could do exactly the same thing (i.e. trimming individual characters no matter in what pattern they appear) - Thank you for the hint Ramblin' Man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex `^[+\-= ]+` should work for you.
This should match 1 or more characters from the start of the line. If non of these character are at the start of the line then nothing will be replaced.

You should be able to use it like so `SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE( <field>, "^[+\-= ]+", "" ) FROM <table>;`

Comment: thank you Aerox, after fixing some syntax issues, your solution worked quite well. This is the final version: REGEXP_REPLACE(input, '^[+-= ]*', '' )

Comment: Thanks, apologies for the syntax issues, I haven't used Oracle for a couple of years now.

Answer (score 1):

In 11g, you can use [`REGEXP_SUBSTR` with subexpressions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions150.htm#SQLRF06303):

```
SQL> SELECT regexp_substr(txt, '^([- +=]*)(.*)', 1, 1, '', '2') reg
  2    FROM (SELECT ' ++ -+= =  - -=  +ABCD EFG + XYD' txt FROM dual);
REG
--------------
ABCD EFG + XYD
```

Comment: Thank you Vincent, your solution works perfectly well, but it seems that we can also achieve the same result by using the simpler regext_replace, as in the comment to AeroX's answer.